# django - reusing a login template

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm just curious if I'm doing this right.

I'm coding a private section of a website and wrote a login view which throws up a login window. I want to reuse this view for several urls which all go to a different views once  access is granted. It doesn't appear that you can pass arguments in the statements in urls.py, so I gave the login view an extra argument `redirect`

```
def login(request, redirect):
    code to read the login form and parse the POST input
    if POST and loginSuccessful:
        return redirect(request)
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html', context)
```

...and made specific urls each activate a different one-liner such as `login_to_admin` which simply returns the login view with a redirect argument.

```
def login_to_admin(request):
    return login(request, admin)

def login_to_beta(beta):
    return login(request, beta)
```

Everything works, I'm just wondering if this is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It doesn't appear that you can pass arguments in the statements in
>   urls.py

[You can, actually.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions)

The third item in the url conf can be a dictionary of kwargs which will be passed your view function.

```
(r'^my_url/$', 'login', {'redirect': admin}),
(r'^my_other_url/$', 'login', {'redirect': beta}),
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [login required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator), as this'll make your code easier to maintain.

There's nothing wrong as such with your approach, but it's less generic and thus more prone to unexpected behaviour and oversights.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add extra field to login form e. g. next, which will contain correct url. And after validating form and logging in redirect user